# Extra unexpected div appearing when inspecting website

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tailwind-css, hidden

I'm making a purley front end admin dashboard using tailwindcss to practice making a responsive site. I've got the mobile layout complete and now am working on the desktop version.

Now that I've started to make the site responsive I've got the sidebar in the position that I want, however the flex row inside of it appears to be showing a div that I haven't coded when I inspect the page (the div on the right of the house icon shouldn't be there, I haven't written any code for it at all). [image: Extra div]

I have no idea why this div is appearing because it's only visible when inspecting the parent div for the home icon and text. While this doesn't break my code I'm just curious as to why its happening so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**Specific code where the issues happening:**

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Admin Dashboard</title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com?plugins=forms,typography,aspect-ratio,line-clamp"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div
      class="box-border px-10 py-8 flex flex-col items-center min-h-screen md:grid md:grid-cols-[1fr,3.5fr] md:p-0"
    >
      <div
        class="sticky top-0 px-5 py-3 h-fit w-full min-w-sm rounded-xl border border-gray-200 shadow-lg flex items-center justify-around bg-white md:h-full md:items-start md:p-8 md:rounded-none"
      >
        <div
          class="flex w-full justify-around md:flex-col md:gap-y-6 md:justify-start"
        >
          <div
            class="flex flex-col cursor-pointer hover:scale-125 ease-in duration-300 w-12 items-center md:flex-row md:gap-x-4"
          >
            <img class="scale-110" src="./images/home.svg" />
            <p class="hidden md:inline md:font-bold md:text-2xl md:my-2">
              Home
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**All of my code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Admin Dashboard</title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com?plugins=forms,typography,aspect-ratio,line-clamp"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div
      class="box-border px-10 py-8 flex flex-col items-center min-h-screen md:grid md:grid-cols-[1fr,3.5fr] md:p-0"
    >
      <div
        class="sticky top-0 px-5 py-3 h-fit w-full min-w-sm rounded-xl border border-gray-200 shadow-lg flex items-center justify-around bg-white md:h-full md:items-start md:p-8 md:rounded-none"
      >
        <div
          class="flex w-full justify-around md:flex-col md:gap-y-6 md:justify-start"
        >
          <div
            class="flex flex-col cursor-pointer hover:scale-125 ease-in duration-300 w-12 items-center md:flex-row md:gap-x-4"
          >
            <img class="scale-110" src="./images/home.svg" />
            <p class="hidden md:inline md:font-bold md:text-2xl md:my-2">
              Home
            </p>
          </div>
          <div
            class="flex flex-col cursor-pointer hover:scale-125 ease-in duration-300 w-12 items-center md:flex-row"
          >
            <img class="scale-110" src="./images/profile.svg" />
          </div>
          <div
            class="flex flex-col cursor-pointer hover:scale-125 ease-in duration-300 w-12 items-center md:flex-row"
          >
            <img class="scale-110" src="./images/message.svg" />
          </div>
          <div
            class="flex flex-col cursor-pointer hover:scale-125 ease-in duration-300 w-12 items-center md:flex-row"
          >
            <img class="scale-110" src="./images/menu.svg" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="md:relative md:p-8">
        <div class="flex w-full min-w-sm mt-5 mb-3 items-center">
          <div class="text-5xl"></div>
          <div class="mx-5">
            <p>Hi there,</p>
            <p class="font-bold text-2xl">Jay Sean</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="border-t w-full"></div>
        <div class="flex w-full min-w-sm justify-start">
          <p class="font-bold text-2xl my-2">Your Projects</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flex flex-col gap-y-4">
          <div
            class="p-4 h-fit w-full min-w-sm rounded-xl border border-gray-200 shadow-md bg-white border-l-8 border-l-yellow-500"
          >
            <p class="font-bold text-2xl my-2">Super Cool Project</p>
            <div class="border-b w-full"></div>

            <p class="mt-2 line-clamp-1">
              Proin convallis enim consequat, imperdiet justo eget, pulvinar
              purus. Vestibulum ac pretium est. Nam in libero at turpis rhoncus
              ullamcorper a ut ex. Aenean ut gravida dolor. Etiam tincidunt
              hendrerit mattis. Nam ac ornare metus, at euismod ipsum. Donec non
              ultrices dolor. Duis gravida dui quis sapien rutrum venenatis.
              Aenean id nibh congue dui tristique mattis nec vel risus.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div
            class="p-4 h-fit w-full min-w-sm rounded-xl border border-gray-200 shadow-md bg-white border-l-8 border-l-yellow-500"
          >
            <p class="font-bold text-2xl my-2">Less Cool Project</p>
            <div class="border-b w-full"></div>

            <p class="mt-2 line-clamp-1">
              Aliquam eget dui nibh. Curabitur eget auctor tortor, id volutpat
              odio. In condimentum quam dictum, vulputate nunc id, fringilla
              lorem. Quisque consectetur ante sed felis finibus, vitae dapibus
              eros semper. In eget tincidunt metus. Proin eget rutrum erat, id
              rutrum elit. Nunc non nisi dui. Maecenas in purus augue. Cras
              pellentesque rhoncus lectus in varius. In gravida nibh orci, eget
              pretium felis vehicula a. Integer dolor odio, laoreet non ipsum
              et, euismod
            </p>
          </div>
          <div
            class="p-4 h-fit w-full min-w-sm rounded-xl border border-gray-200 shadow-md bg-white border-l-8 border-l-yellow-500"
          >
            <p class="font-bold text-2xl my-2">Impossible App</p>
            <div class="border-b w-full"></div>

            <p class="mt-2 line-clamp-1">
              Phasellus vulputate faucibus lectus, vitae ultrices orci. Nunc
              consectetur lacus id venenatis aliquam. Cras commodo lorem orci,
              sit amet posuere tortor posuere sit amet. Nunc porta tellus id
              ipsum varius mollis. Donec id convallis libero, a rutrum mi.
              Mauris quam tortor, aliquet a tortor id, vehicula euismod justo.
              Vestibulum ullamcorper sed nisl eu mollis. Vestibulum ante ipsum
              primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae;
              Curabitur interdum od
            </p>
          </div>
          <div
            class="p-4 h-fit w-full min-w-sm rounded-xl border border-gray-200 shadow-md bg-white border-l-8 border-l-yellow-500"
          >
            <p class="font-bold text-2xl my-2">Ad Blocker</p>
            <div class="border-b w-full"></div>

            <p class="mt-2 line-clamp-1">
              Pellentesque ex enim, auctor non tincidunt ut, pellentesque eget
              urna. Quisque quis nisl neque. Phasellus placerat ultrices sem,
              vel convallis erat elementum eu. Phasellus finibus malesuada quam,
              sed consequat augue sagittis eget. Phasellus auctor varius est eu
              tempor. Maecenas sollicitudin, lectus sit amet sagittis
              vestibulum, velit libero eleifend dolor, ut finibus risus nibh id
              dolor. Nullam in lectus dolor. Nulla vel arcu lorem. Ut eleifend,
              nulla vitae varius
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="border-t mt-6 w-full"></div>
        <div class="flex w-full min-w-sm justify-start">
          <p class="font-bold text-2xl my-2">Your Projects</p>
        </div>
        <div
          class="p-4 h-fit w-full min-w-sm rounded-xl border border-gray-200 shadow-md bg-white border-l-8 border-l-yellow-500"
        >
          <p class="font-bold text-2xl my-2">Site Maintanence</p>
          <p class="mt-2 line-clamp-1 mb-2">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
          </p>
          <div class="border-b w-full"></div>
          <p class="font-bold text-2xl my-2">Community Share Day</p>
          <p class="mt-2 line-clamp-1 mb-2">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
          </p>
          <div class="border-b w-full"></div>
          <p class="font-bold text-2xl my-2">Updated Privacy Policy</p>
          <p class="mt-2 line-clamp-1">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="border-t my-6 w-full"></div>
        <div
          class="p-4 h-fit w-full min-w-sm rounded-xl border border-gray-200 shadow-md bg-white border-l-8 border-l-yellow-500"
        >
          <div class="flex flex-col gap-y-6">
            <div class="flex justify-between">
              <p class="font-bold text-xl my-2">Your Team</p>
              <p class="text-purple-500 text-xl my-2">See all</p>
            </div>
            <div class="flex justify-evenly gap-x-3">
              <img class="w-12" src="./images/person-profile.svg" />
              <div class="flex flex-col justify-around ml-3">
                <p class="text-gray-400">UI Designer</p>
                <p class="font-bold text-xl">Billy Bob Lewis</p>
              </div>
              <img class="w-8" src="./images/more.svg" />
            </div>
            <div class="flex justify-evenly gap-x-3">
              <img class="w-12" src="./images/person-profile.svg" />
              <div class="flex flex-col justify-around ml-3">
                <p class="text-gray-400">Front End Developer</p>
                <p class="font-bold text-xl">Sarah Pligh</p>
              </div>
              <img class="w-8" src="./images/more.svg" />
            </div>
            <div class="flex justify-evenly gap-x-3">
              <img class="w-12" src="./images/person-profile.svg" />
              <div class="flex flex-col justify-around ml-3">
                <p class="text-gray-400">Marketing Lead</p>
                <p class="font-bold text-xl">Patrick Stewart</p>
              </div>
              <img class="w-8" src="./images/more.svg" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="border-t my-6 w-full"></div>

        <div class="flex flex-col gap-y-4 w-full min-w-sm">
          <div
            class="px-2 py-4 h-fit w-full min-w-sm rounded-xl border border-gray-200 shadow-md bg-white border-l-8 border-l-yellow-500"
          >
            <div class="flex items-center justify-center justify-around">
              <div
                class="flex items-center justify-center rounded-full w-12 h-12 bg-pink-500"
              >
                <img class="scale-125" src="./images/credit_card.svg" />
              </div>
              <p class="font-bold text-xl my-2">Budget</p>
              <p class="text-xl my-2">$750.00</p>
              <div
                class="flex justify-center w-16 bg-green-300 rounded-md px-2"
              >
                <p class="text-green-600">30%</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div
            class="px-2 py-4 h-fit w-full min-w-sm rounded-xl border border-gray-200 shadow-md bg-white border-l-8 border-l-yellow-500"
          >
            <div class="flex items-center justify-center justify-around">
              <div
                class="flex items-center justify-center rounded-full w-12 h-12 bg-purple-500"
              >
                <img class="scale-125" src="./images/users.svg" />
              </div>
              <p class="font-bold text-xl my-2">Projects</p>
              <p class="text-xl my-2">215</p>
              <div
                class="flex justify-center w-16 bg-green-300 rounded-md px-2"
              >
                <p class="text-green-600">23%</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div
            class="px-2 py-4 h-fit w-full min-w-sm rounded-xl border border-gray-200 shadow-md bg-white border-l-8 border-l-yellow-500"
          >
            <div class="flex items-center justify-center justify-around">
              <div
                class="flex items-center justify-center rounded-full w-12 h-12 bg-blue-500"
              >
                <img class="scale-125" src="./images/clock.svg" />
              </div>
              <p class="font-bold text-xl my-2">Total Hours</p>
              <p class="text-xl my-2">1.400</p>
              <div class="flex justify-center w-16 bg-red-300 rounded-md px-2">
                <p class="text-red-600">10%</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div
            class="px-2 py-4 h-fit w-full min-w-sm rounded-xl border border-gray-200 shadow-md bg-white border-l-8 border-l-yellow-500"
          >
            <div class="flex items-center justify-center justify-around">
              <div
                class="flex items-center justify-center rounded-full w-12 h-12 bg-orange-500"
              >
                <img class="scale-125" src="./images/briefcase.svg" />
              </div>
              <p class="font-bold text-xl my-2">Work Load</p>
              <p class="text-xl my-2">95%</p>
              <div
                class="flex justify-center w-16 bg-green-300 rounded-md px-2"
              >
                <p class="text-green-600">13%</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Based on your image provided, that's not in your HTML. That div is a selector in your stylesheet.

Comment: You were probably hovering over the 4th div down and the browser is showing you some of the classes associated with that div, ie the start of a selector. It hasn’t shown all of it for reasons of space. There is no extra div added to your code.

Comment: there is nothing wrong here, this `div` exists and it's the parent of `img` and `p` it might look  weird because you specify the width to be `w-12` if you delete that and look here in line 5 it will be clear https://play.tailwindcss.com/j7TyFD25RO